# Javascript Code Coverage tool for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, code-coverage

I've got a rather hideous and large javascript file that I've inherited from a dev I loathe.  There is a lot of dead code, and I find I've spent a lot of time refactoring functions that aren't even called.

Ideally, I just want something that can tie into the js engine and keep track of when and how many times functions are called.

In FF, I can get a list of the functions by walking the window object, and dynamically wrap them all in a method that would log the call to them, and then call the function as normal.

Unfortunately, in IE, I can't use this as I can't seem to find a way to get a list of all the functions that have been loaded.  And I can't run this app in FF, as it's horribly browser specific.  At last count there were 138 lines containing "new ActiveXObject(...)"

Help, either with a tool that can do this, or at the very least, a way to get a list of the functions that IE7 has loaded from the user script.

Thanks
-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [JSCoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/).

> JSCoverage is a tool that measures
>   code coverage for JavaScript programs.
>
> JSCoverage works by instrumenting the
>   JavaScript code used in web pages.
>   Code coverage statistics are collected
>   while the instrumented JavaScript code
>   is executed in a web browser.

The instrumentation can be done on-the-fly if you set the JSCoverage Server to run as an HTTP proxy and configure your browser to go through it.

One way to use it is:

1. Launch JSCoverage Server in proxy mode:

```
jscoverage-server --proxy --verbose
```

2. Configure your browser to you use localhost:8080 as the HTTP proxy.
3. Add the following bookmarklet, making sure the relative path to jscoverage is correct:

```
javascript:void(window.open('jscoverage/jscoverage.html'))
```

4. Run your tests.
5. Run the bookmarklet. It will popup a new window that shows you the coverage results.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to use that with this system.  
It's full of frames and ajax.

Comment: I'll add more details to my answer.

Comment: Looks like it would work, unfortunately, I can't change my browsers proxy settings...we're pretty locked down here.

Comment: You don't need to use it in proxy mode. First load up jscoverage.html in your browser and then enter the URL to your application in the text field. For that, I think you may need to pre-instrument your JS files using the jscoverage command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firebug extension for JS Code Coverage...

FirebugCodeCoverage 0.1 (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4837)

Unfortunately, its not currently updated for the latest version of FF.